# rake db:migrate with rails '~> 5.1.4', sqlite3 and sequel-rails gives NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations, sequel

I'm working on a simple application with the following gems:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sequel-rails'
```

When I try to create any migration, following the [instructions](https://github.com/TalentBox/sequel-rails), I get the "rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant" error. For example, if I'm running this:
`rails generate migration create_users`, the output error would be:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateUsers
```

Same happens with any model generation.
My `application.rb` file reads:

```
  require_relative 'boot'

  require "rails"
  require "action_controller/railtie"
  require "action_mailer/railtie"
  require "sprockets/railtie"
  require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
  # Pick the frameworks you want:
  require "active_model/railtie"
  require "active_job/railtie"
  # require "active_record/railtie"
  require "action_controller/railtie"
  require "action_mailer/railtie"
  require "action_view/railtie"
  require "action_cable/engine"
  require "sprockets/railtie"
  require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
  require 'rails/all'

  # Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
  # you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

  module MyApp
    class Application < Rails::Application
      # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
      config.load_defaults 5.1
      # Allowed options: :sql, :ruby.
      config.sequel.schema_format = :sql
      # Whether to dump the schema after successful migrations.
      # Defaults to false in production and test, true otherwise.
      config.sequel.schema_dump = true
      config.sequel.load_database_tasks = true
      config.sequel.load_database_tasks = :sequel
      config.sequel.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
      # config.sequel.after_connect = proc do
      #   Sequel::Model.plugin :timestamps, update_on_create: true
      # end
      # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
      # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
      # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    end
  end
```

The `database.yml` has:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3 # Also accept sqlite3
  database: db/mydatabase.sqlite # Path to db relative to Rails root
```

And my migration `20180214121521_create_users.rb`content is:

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    create_table :users do
      primary_key :id
    end
  end
end
```

Any help to sort this out would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: try removing  require 'rails/all' from application.rb.

Comment: do you have migration file already ? and you try to create new migration ?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy, removing `rails/all` throws: "Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' (see --tasks)"

Comment: @Vishal, yes. the migration filed is mentioned in the question: "And my migration `20180214121521_create_users.rb` content is:

    Sequel.migration do
      change do
      create_table :users do
        primary_key :id
      end
    end
  end"

Comment: @RalucaP. did you configure your `config/environments/development.rb` `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb`

Comment: @Vishal, I generated the app with `--skip-active-record`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove: `require 'rails/all'` and the `config.sequel.load_database_tasks = :sequel`. I works fine now.